# Where is the "bar area" in Florence?

Tags: florence, nightlife

Situation:
Having arrived in Firenze by train a couple of hours earlier, settled into a  hostel (laundry & fresh clothes, ah!), and seen the amazing Duomo briefly (illuminated at night), I was wondering around the streets between [the Duomo](http://goo.gl/maps/60Y8e) and [the hostel](http://goo.gl/maps/zYudM) for some while. For a Friday night, around 8-9 pm, it was very quiet, I thought. I saw many restaurants (pizzerias and trattorias) with people inside, but only one or two bars, which looked like they're just closing. And this was right in the middle of the city, weekend starting! Granted, it was November and not very warm outside, but come on.

Question:
**Where are all the bars**, all the people, in Florence on a weekend night?
Is there any major concentration of nightlife spots?
(Show it on the map, please?)

Comment: Disclosure: this is the exact question I asked soon afterwards at my hostel. I got a pretty good answer as well, which I'll post shortly. Others are free to answer too, of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main bar area is along **Via de' Benci** / **Via Giuseppe Verdi**, and some of the side streets. There are lots of different kinds of bars and some clubs there, [starting from near the bridge](http://goo.gl/maps/dYF2s) (Ponte alle Grazie) [until Via Pietrapiana](http://goo.gl/maps/ea698), maybe 500 m north.

See the map, just like the hostel guy drew it:

[image: Photo of the map I received from the hostel]
<sup>The map I got from the hostel, with main bar area marked on the right-hand side</sup>

It was quite busy, although I'd expect it to be *really* busy in summer.

There may be "lesser" bar areas too, e.g. across the river [around piazza San Spirito](http://goo.gl/maps/tiBy2) (also marked on the map). And someone mentioned that some (fancier?) nightclubs are located quite far in the suburbs, a taxi ride away. I didn't try those.
Also, there's [a rather good Irish pub](https://foursquare.com/v/the-fiddlers-elbow--irish-pub/4bec25659fa3ef3b8c4f80c9) on piazza S. Maria Novella, closer to the central station.

Comment: I did a quick google maps search for "bars" in Florence, and the concentration of them in that area seems to match that map above.  It also shows a few other smaller groupings in other neighbourhoods as you scroll/pan around, but this area does seem to have the highlights.